# application C++/Java dependency

Tags: java, c++, jvm, java-native-interface, dependencies

I have a builder C++ application that create a VM to process metadata from file.
My application comunicate with my ExtractMetadata.jar with JNI.

When i test that with my IDE, it works fine(the process metadata works fine). But when i create my setup application and i run that the process metadata is not run fine.

I logged that and it seems the class is not found.

```
jclass cls;
jmethodID midAllfield, midConstructor, mid1;
jobject newObj;
jboolean isCopy;
FILE *FileMeta;
String strFields, strValueFields, strFld;
JavaVM* jvm;
JNIEnv* env;
//  Attach this Thread to JVM
jint succGetJVM = gl_env->GetJavaVM(&jvm);
int succ1 = succGetJVM;
if(succGetJVM!=0)
    logging(sExtractMetaLogFile, "\n GetJavaVM(&jvm) : failure ");
else {
    logging(sExtractMetaLogFile, "\n GetJavaVM(&jvm) : Success :");
    logging(sExtractMetaLogFile, IntToStr(succ1));
}

jint  succAttchd = jvm->AttachCurrentThread((void**)&env, NULL);
int succ2 = succAttchd;
if(succAttchd!=0)
    logging(sExtractMetaLogFile, "\n AttachCurrentThread : failure ");
else{
    logging(sExtractMetaLogFile, "\n AttachCurrentThread : Success : ");
    logging(sExtractMetaLogFile, IntToStr(succ2));
}

cls = (*env).FindClass("ExtractMetaData");

jthrowable exc = env->ExceptionOccurred();
 if (exc) {
     jclass newExcCls;
     try {
        env->ExceptionDescribe();
     }
     catch (...) {
        ShowMessage("env->ExceptionDescribe()");
        return;
     }
     logging(sExtractMetaLogFile, "\n ExceptionDescribe : ");
     env->ExceptionClear();
 }
if(cls !=0)
{
       //....
}
else
{
    logging(sExtractMetaLogFile, "\n Tika Thread Not Found class : ExtractMetaData ");
}
```

And my log result is

```
GetJavaVM(&jvm) : Success :0
AttachCurrentThread : Success : 
ExceptionDescribe :  
Tika Thread Not Found class : ExtractMetaData
```

Why it works fine when i start my application from my IDE and not work when run it from my installed application?!!

Comment: I guess apache tika module not found./org.apache.tika/

Comment: So, how to fix that or test that?

Comment: When I run MyApplication.exe from C:/Programe file/../bin/myapplication.exe (with double click on this exe), the process metadata works fine!!!!!!! but when i start myapplication.exe  from shortcut icon on desktop the process don't work!!!!! and i have on my log file Class not found!!

Comment: Can u put Working folder inside ur Shortcut to C:/Programe file/../bin/?

Comment: I mean after install my application when i start my application with shortcut created on desktop the process of metadata can't found a class in my jar file.. but when i start the application with double click on exe on bin folder the process work fine!!

Comment: Thats I understood. Can u check in properties of Shortcut field Working Folder. Also are u installing App on Same PC?

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\bin\MyApplication.exe" this directory in my shortcut

Comment: Thats Target field. Check Field "Start in"

Comment: Nothing in Field "Startin" !!

Comment: i added manually the field Start in , Now the process metadata it work!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So answer:

open properties of shortcut and set field "Start in" to "C:\Program Files (x86)\xxx\bin\"

Comment: I set this field in my project InstallShield. Now my programm work correctly. Thx @Boris